# Using xCode 7 beta 5 with CocoaPod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I just downloaded xCode 7 Beta 5. One of the main reasons is some extra features that I'll need with auto layout. I need to use CocoaPods for my project and it give me errors even though that it used to work in the past. I even tried creating a new project and installing CocoaPods to it, it gave me 34 warnings all of which are in the libraries themselves.

FYI the libraries that I'm using are:

- 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
- 'Google/SignIn'
- 'FBSDKCoreKit'
- 'FBSDKLoginKit'
- 'FBSDKShareKit'
- 'Fabric'
- 'TwitterKit'
- 'TwitterCore'

These are the libraries that are causing the warnings:

1. Bolts w/ 2 warnings
2. AFNetworking w/ 9 warnings
3. FBSDKCoreKit w/ 14 warnings
4. FBSDKShareKit w/ 1 warnings
5. FBSDKLoginKit w/ 8 warnings

Answer (score 0):

pod update

and add this to the top of your podfile

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

Comment: It didn't work. Plus I haven't installed CocoaPods using github. I used the command line

Comment: Yes in the command line type pod update. You added that line to your podfile and did pod I install?